# Why is passing tests showing in the bitbucket pipeline log

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, bitbucket, pipeline

I was wondering if anyone has seen this happen to them before/ has suggestions to remove this white noise.

I've noticed recently I've been getting passing tests showing up in the test log. The only change I have done prior to this happening is updating the chrome version to V98 so this shouldnt be causing this to happen?

Ideally I would love to startup a dashboard reporting of some sort (similar to how Azure Devops has all the different widgets but I dont see anything in bitbucket to do a similar output)

[image]

Edit:

There was no 'code', the image just shows an example of a passing test that still output to the log file (instead of only failed tests showing in the log)

Stackoverflow is also pretty horrible for formatting. For me the image is clear too...

```
Starting Check the user can't see the organisation settings

Given the user is logged in as a reviewer
-> done: Login.GivenTheUserIsLoggedIn("reviewer") (2.0s)

When the user expands the user dropdown menu
-> done: Product.WhenTheUserExpandsTheUserDropdownMenu() (2.6s)

Then the user can't see organisation settings
-> done: Profile.ThenTheUserCantSeeOrganisationSettings("organisation sett...") (0.0s)
```

Comment: Please copy and paste text into your question, and format it as code. Images are difficult to read.

Comment: @GregBurghardt added another example to the original text.